# Eclipse(Indigo) launch failed after google app engine plugin install

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, crash

After installing the google app engine plugin, eclipse failed to launch. 
Following is the error statement i got

> Job found still running after platform shutdown. Jobs should be
>   canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown:
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchActivityHelper$4

I am using eclipse on Linux(Fedora 16).

Can someone kindly help me in resolving this issue?

Thanks

Comment: This link might help you you both seem to have the exact same problem: http://expertdevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/07/eclipse-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem Solved.

The problem is with

> org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui_3.6.2.v20110826-0100.jar

Removed it and eclipse is working.

Comment: I changed my workspace which also solved my problem. Btw, if somebody finds the location of the above .jar file, please update it in the above answer and make it concise.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem (eclipse 3.7 and org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui_3.6.5)

Answer (score 0):

The location is /opt/eclipse/plugins. I am still getting this error after deleting jar. I am using Eclipse Indigo and using ubuntu 12.04. I think there is some other problem for it.

J.M.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac the jars are located e.g. here (I am running both indigo and juno)

```
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui_3.8.1.v20120725-0100.jar
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui_3.8.2.v20120916-1200.jar
/Applications/eclipse_indigo/plugins /org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui_3.6.5.v20120215-0100.jar
/Applications/eclipse_indigo/plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui_3.8.2.v20120916-1200.jar
```

I ended up following
http://expertdevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/07/eclipse-troubleshooting.html
which suggest to remove the files. And since I did not understand which files I ended up removing:
rm //.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/.indexes/*